# JQuery DateTime Picker not working with struts 1 jsp code

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts-1

I followed the link: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ and tried to implement the datetime picker in my struts code. My jsp page looks something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
<script text/javascript src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script text/javascript src="scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script text/javascript src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">



$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  inline:true
});


</script>

<div class="clear">
                            <label>
                                <bean:message key="label.from.message" bundle="labels" />
                                <span style="color: #db290b;">*</span>
                                <bean:message key="prompt.colon" bundle="labels" />
                            </label>
                            <html:text property="requestStartTime" styleId="requestStartTime" readonly="true"/>
                            <!-- <a href="javascript:NewCal('requestStartTime','ddmmyyyy',true,24,'dropdown',true,'300','375')">
                                <img style="margin-left: 6px;" src="images/cal.gif"
                                    width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Select From Date">
                            </a> --!>
                            <input type="text" id="datetimepicker"/><input type="button" onclick="$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({value:'2011/12/11 12:00'})" value="set inline value 2011/12/11 12:00"/>
                        </div>
                    </logic:equal>
```

The code which is commented is the existing date picker code where I am trying to use jquery to insert time. Please let me know what do you see anything wrong or I am totally wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using this Jquery plugin for date time picker.[JQuery datetime picker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

It is simple and easy to use,i am using it currently without any problem,it got rich API documentation as well.